# AngularJS ng-model binding issue with input type=email element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a wierd issue.
The email input value is not logged, however the password value is logged.
Any idea guys?

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
    <div class="row" style="height: 50px;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4" >

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="emailinput">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailinput"
                       ng-model="user.email"
                       placeholder="Enter Email Address">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="passwordinput">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordinput"
                       ng-model="user.pass"
                       placeholder="Enter Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary ladda-button"
                        ng-click="verifyCredentials()"
                        data-style="expand-left">
                     <span class="ladda-label">Login</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="passwordinput">
                    <a href="forgotpassword.html">Forgot Password?</a>
                </label>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My angular code is as below.

```
var app = angular.module('bookie',[]);

app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.verifyCredentials = function(){
        console.log($scope.user);
    }
});
```

Comment: Neither of your `<input>` fields have a `name` attribute, which is required to `POST` data.

Comment: I'm trying to get them through angular. The password value is shown in the console log. But the email is not shown

Comment: can you share a plunker?

Comment: It sounds as though you may be looking for two-way binding. Are you attempting to log what the user inputs into each field? In that case, you're looking for `{{$scope.user.pass}}` and `{{$scope.user.email}}`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I'm trying to get the email,password and send to an api to verify them. The console only shows the password. The email field is not even shown as an array object element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email will only show when it is a legal email address:

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-init="user={}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="emailinput">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailinput"
               ng-model="user.email"
               placeholder="Enter Email Address">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="passwordinput">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordinput"
               ng-model="user.pass"
               placeholder="Enter Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary ladda-button"
                ng-click="verifyCredentials()"
                data-style="expand-left">
             <span class="ladda-label">Login</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="passwordinput">
            <a href="forgotpassword.html">Forgot Password?</a>
        </label>
    </div>

     {{user | json}}
</div>
```

Comment: holly shizzle. u are right. u deserve more than 10.

Answer (score 0):

**It will display email only when the user types the correct email address (i.e -something@xyz.com)**

```
<label>EMAIL:</label>
<input type="email" ng-model="uemail"  name="ueamil" placeholder="Enter EMAIL">
<h4> EMAIL: {{uemail}}</h4>
```